# Why the activation of this Func works?

Tags: c#

I can't understand how this is working.

`Test` expects to get a method with the signature of `InterfaceObj` as input, but we never pass it in `Test2` (the `Test` itself holds a reference to `Actual` that implements `InterfaceObj` and acts as the input, but `Test2` doesn't know it.. or is it?)

`Actual` implements `InterfaceObj`.

```cs
public bool Test(Func<InterfaceObj, bool> pointerToMethod)
{
    Actual actual = new Actual();

    return pointerToMethod(actual);
}

public bool Test2()
{
    return Test(x => x.Test());
}
```

Comment: Well, you're passing a lambda to `Test`, which contains the implementation you desire to be called. In `Test`, you're calling your lambda function with custom parameters. You've already defined everything you need in `Test`'s head

Comment: Can we assume that InterfaceObj contains a method `bool Tesdt()`?

Comment: Would it be clearer to you if it was written as `return Test((InterfaceObj x) => x.Test());`?

Comment: You *are* passing a func to the question's `Test`, it's `x => x.Test()`. It seems `InterfaceObj` itself has a `bool Test()` method

Comment: @GSerg Actually it is.
So we don't need to implicitly write the type of the input because the compiler knows the type from the signature of Test?

Comment: I think it confuses me because we don't explicitly write the type of the input.. and because the output is activation of a method inside x that return a bool (and not some explicit logic that return bool).
it feels a bit weird, but ok.
Thanks everyone!
*And for those who asked- yes, InterfaceObj contains bool test() that Actual implements.

Comment: @Blizz Yes, it's called [type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1163-type-inference). The output is not activation of a method either; a `Func` is code to be executed later, not the result of executing that code. You create a Func that describes "call Test() on InterfaceObj", you pass that Func to Test, Test executes it by giving it `actual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the lambda parameters can be automatically [inferred by the compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1163-type-inference). You could also specify the type explicitly:

```
public bool Test2()
{
    return Test((InterfaceObj x) => x.Test());
}
```

`x => y` can be assigned to a `Func<T, TResult>` with `x` being type `T` and `y` being type `TResult`.

And since your method `Test()` only accepts `Func<InterfaceObj, bool>`, `x` can only be of type `InterfaceObj`.

It also works when assigning a variable:

```
Func<InterfaceObj, bool> myFunction = x => x != null; // x is of type InterfaceObj
```

The lambda itself is *not* called, you still need to invoke it:

```
InterfaceObj obj = ...;
bool result1 = myFunction.Invoke(obj);
// or, shorter:
bool result2 = myFunction(obj);
```

NB Instead of `Func<T, bool>`, it is usually better to use the more specific `Predicate<T>` which also provides more semantic value to callers of your method.